# Is there a way to run a SQL query within Jenkins against RDS (Oracle) without using SQL Plus Script Runner Plugin

Tags: linux, oracle, jenkins, amazon-rds

Trying to find an easy way to run a simple SQL query against RDS(Oracle) using Jenkins. SQL Plus Script Runner Plugin for Jenkins is not an option due to not having the rights to install the plugin. Looking for a step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, you may be able to use the powershell cmdlet https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-RDSDBInstance.html if you have the powershell plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/rds-code-change-deployment/
Storing credentials with secret manager and using them by Jenkins is good actually.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.